# IdentityServer4 - Delegated access tokens for clients

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

In IdentityServer4 you can specify an [extension grand](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant) to enable delegated access tokens for users, so if a webservice needs to call another webservice during a request from a user, it can request a new access token from the IdentityServer with a valid scope and audience. My issue is, that this grant is thought to be used "on behalf of the interactive user", which leads to my question:

**If my client calls a webservice which needs to call another webservice during the request, how can i create a delegated access token?**

I tried to modify the example from the documentation, but the extension grand expects a token from a user, which holds a "sub" claim, and not from a client, which does not hold a "sub" claim.

The client is a daemon application, so it runs fully automated and without any user interaction, and is authenticated with the client credentials flow.

To clarify what i mean:

Here we see an use case, if a user is present:
[image: Flow if a user is present]

1. User accesses a UI
2. UI redirects the user to the identity server to authenticate (With the Authorization Code Flow + PCKE). The UI gets the access token back
3. The UI calls an WebApi A with the access token
4. The WebApi A needs to access the WebApi B, but the access token was meant for WebApi A. Therefore the WebApi A asks the IdentityServer for a delegated access token to access WebApi B.
5. The IdentityServer provides the delegated access token.
6. The new access token is passed along to the WebApi B.

Here we see the same use case, but no user is present and a daemon application does the same thing:

[image: Flow if no user is present]

1. The deamon appliaction authenticates against the IdentityServer with the Client Credentails Flow and gets the access token back
2. The deamon appliaction calls an WebApi A with the access token
3. The WebApi A needs to access the WebApi B, but the access token was meant for WebApi A. Therefore the WebApi A asks the IdentityServer for a delegated access token to access WebApi B.
4. **How to get the IdentityServer to provide a the delegated access token for the client?**
5. The new access token is passed along to the WebApi B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my issue. You can extend the given example implementation of the delegation grand and extend it in a way, that a delegation token is issued for a client:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
            var oldToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("token");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldToken))
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
                return;
            }

            var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(oldToken);
            if (result.IsError)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
                return;
            }

            var sub = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;
            if (sub != null)
            {
                // The old token had a user context
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, GrantType);
            }
            // The "magic" is the part below
            else
            {
                // The old token had a client context
                var client = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("client_id", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(client?.Value))
                {
                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidClient);
                    return;
                }

                context.Request.ClientId = client.Value;
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(new Dictionary<string, object>());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For machine to machine (Service to service) communication you typically use the client credientials grant. This allows services to communicate even if no user is present. The userid (Subject) is typically included in the API calls that is protected using this flow.

See this [article](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html?highlight=Client%20Credentials#machine-to-machine-communication)

The communication between WebApi-A and WebApi-B can be done using client credentials flow and here you don't need to pass any access token from the user. Instead you pass the subjectId(userID) and optionally some additional claims as part of the API calls between A and B. This way is much simpler and the benefit is that A-B can communicate without any user involved (for example to do workflow style communication in the background).

Comment: My client is authenticated with the client credentails flow/grant. I updated the question with an example use case to clarify my question.

Comment: updated my answer, i think its important to keep it simple in your architecture. Does that answer your question?

Comment: While this surely is an option, this would blow up the size of the requests between the apis quite significantly, depending on how much user data is needed in the scond api. Furthermore the data would have to be passed into any request in any rest route in any service which would lead to more implementation effort than if it would be simply present in the access token.

Comment: Further the delegation approch seems to be the right approach, as described in [Scott Bradys blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Delegation-Patterns-for-OAuth-20) and with [Azure](https://youtu.be/IIQ7QW4bYqA?t=1813) following this approach.

Comment: My thought is that eventually API1 might want to call API2 in the background without the user is involved, perhaps for reporting, workflows, cleanups or other tasks, then you need to add client credentials flow to support that. So now you have two want to communicate between the two APIs, but of course this all depends on your need and complexity. The question is also if API2 can access the user data using some back channel without using tokens. not everything must be done via tokens and the IdentityServer can have an internal API for internal services.

Comment: "My thought is that eventually API1 might want to call API2 in the background without the user is involved, perhaps for reporting, workflows, cleanups or other tasks," thats what the client is intended to trigger. So if i implement two ways of communication, how would i know which way to use during an incoming request, as i only get an token and some functionality specific data? Is there any way to differentiate between an "user" access token and a "client" access token to determine the right way?

Comment: The API2 can only access user data within a token or ask for it with a token. As the are no unrestricted routes, a token is necessary.